# How to use jQuery appendTo only on smaller screen sizes, but return to normal position on larger screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a div that lives in a sidebar on desktop, and when it goes down to mobile (< 992), I'd like that div to go to the bottom of the page under the last div shown in the main content on larger screens (> 992). I have appendTo triggering on both document load and on window resize.

Currently, when I resize the window to less than 992, the div moves down, but when I resize to greater that 992, it stays at the bottom and does not return to the side bar. Here is what I currently have:

```
<div class="sidebar hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <div class="some-div">This should go away on mobile and is not always  present so I can't append the next div to me on bigger screens</div>
  <div class="important-info">This should move to other div on mobile</div>
  <div class="some-div">This should go away on mobile</div>
</div>

<div class="middle-content">
      <div class="stuff">always shown on mobile and desktop</div>
</div>
```

And my JS is:

```
function moveDiv() {
    if ($(window).width() < 992) {
        $('.important-info').appendTo('.middle-content');
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
moveDiv();
$(window).resize(moveDiv);
```

If someone could guide me towards having my content return to the sidebar and go away from the middle content when I'm at bigger screens, that would be great! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: just append it to its previous parent in the else statement ?

Comment: I would recommend that you to use CSS media query to define where you want the div to exist for what resolution; it's less math for the client to have to work through.

Comment: Great first question, by the way. Welcome to SO! (Well... first in a while.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add code to move it back. I used a wrapper to make it easier to get the important info properly positioned between your other elements.

Note that I'm assuming you are using [CSS Media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) queries to hide the `some-div`s and you just need to "physically" reposition `important-info` within the DOM (which can't be done with CSS). If you can figure out how to get away with a pure CSS solution, that's generally more efficient and easier to maintain. I'm assuming you have some requirements that are forcing you to reposition the element within the DOM rather than just restyle it.

```js
function moveDiv() {
    if ($(window).width() < 992) {
        $('.important-info').appendTo('.middle-content');
    } else {
        $('.important-info').appendTo('#important-info-wrapper-desktop');
    }
}
moveDiv();
$(window).resize(moveDiv);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <div class="some-div">This should go away on mobile and is not always  present so I can't append the next div to me on bigger screens</div>
  <div id="important-info-wrapper-desktop">
    <div class="important-info">This should move to other div on mobile</div>
  </div>
  <div class="some-div">This should go away on mobile</div>
</div>

<div class="middle-content">
      <div class="stuff">always shown on mobile and desktop</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @JDB I have implemented your solution. I figured I would have to add another container but I was hoping to avoid adding more markup and had my fingers crossed for that. This does work exactly as expected for me though, so thank you! I've accepted yours as the best answer.

Comment: You could use jQuery to determine which ordinal the important-info DIV has within its parent container (first, second, third, etc) and store that in a javascript variable (perhaps using [jQuery data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)) and then restore it to that position when you append it. But it'd be messier, easier to break, harder to maintain and less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use javascript to make your site responsive. Use CSS media queries. [jsfiddle: responsive layout using css only](https://jsfiddle.net/g7fnrehr/)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .sidebar {
    /* style to display below */
  }
}
```

Comment: CSS won't reposition DOM elements for you.

Comment: @JDB Right, but you don't need to move DOM elements to reposition elements on a page.

Comment: Unfortunately the real application has more than my example and it would be overly complicated to try and reposition elements in the dom through CSS media queries.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that the OP has simplified her code (SSCCE). There may be more going on than simple CSS positioning can handle.

Comment: @Emmy Ah, ok. I was going off what was provided in your example

Comment: @SageArslan no worries! Thanks a bunch for your help anyhow :)

Comment: if you need to reposition code for position using javascript, its because you are doing something horribly wrong.

Maybe in this case its a lot better to duplicate code and use CSS all the way, javascript for this its a nono.

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa - Software design rules are like art "rules" - you learn them so that you can make an informed decision about when and how to break them. If you don't know when and how to make meaningful compromises when creating software, then you'll have real trouble succeeding in a world that doesn't conform neatly to your arbitrary and artificial "best practices". Not that they aren't extremely valuable - they just aren't universal.

Comment: @JDB if you are deleting nodes and adding them from the DOM all the time, thats just bad man, its not because is ugly, its bad because modifying the DOM like that has a lot of impact on the performance.

Comment: @seb Oh... I agree it's not good. But it may be the best possible given many other considerations we are not privy to. I have often done things that make me cringe, but it was the best I could do under the circumstances. It's important to cringe, to not feel comfortable... But it's equally important to have the agility to make those kinds of decisions when the situation requires it. And it's not happening that often... Just when a page width threshold is hit.

Comment: @JDB i totally agree with you in the part of doing what it takes (sometimes doing ugly stuff), but is not simpler to do with css in this case? (simpler and better)